# <int-jms:outbound-gateway> is not receiving reply messages

Tags: spring-integration

My `<int-jms:outbound-gateway>` is not sending messages to destination queue because of which i end up getting MessageTimeoutException.

I tried  which worked perfectly and sent the messages which makes sure that i am getting correct messages on request-channel.

Also i see in logs that my outbound gatway is receiving the messages on requestCh1.
org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway#0 received message: [Payload...]

I am really stuck and dont able to figure out why jms outbound gateway is not sending messages to destination queue.

Any help anybody ?

Config:

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="requestCh1" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="requestCh1" ref="processor" method="processMsg"/>
<bean id="processor" class="com.processor.ProcessorImpl" />

<int-jms:outbound-gateway 
            id="eventPublisherGateway"
            connection-factory="myConnectionFactory"
            request-channel="requestCh1"
            request-destination="qequestQueue"
            reply-channel="responseCh1" 
            reply-destination="responseQueue" 
            receive-timeout="20000">
</int-jms:outbound-gateway>
```

Stacktrace:

```
07-15-2014 13:18:49 [threaPool.Thread-1] DEBUG AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(334) | preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: [Payload MessageTimeoutException content=org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: failed to receive JMS response within timeout of: 20000ms][Headers={id=7c81f473-e60e-30fa-b031-8106b3a2fff0, timestamp=1405444729344}]
07-15-2014 13:18:49 [threaPool.Thread-1] DEBUG AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(72) | (inner bean)#3dd4a538 received message: [Payload MessageTimeoutException content=org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: failed to receive JMS response within timeout of: 20000ms][Headers={id=7c81f473-e60e-30fa-b031-8106b3a2fff0, timestamp=1405444729344}]
07-15-2014 13:18:49 [threaPool.Thread-1] ERROR LoggingHandler.handleMessageInternal(145) | org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: failed to receive JMS response within timeout of: 20000ms
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(JmsOutboundGateway.java:667)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:255)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:223)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:260)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:241)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:205)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:199)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:74)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:205)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:284)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Adding JMS Message this gateways is sending with correlation id.

JMS Message class: jms_text

```
JMSType:         null
  JMSDeliveryMode: 2
  JMSExpiration:   0
  JMSPriority:     4
  JMSMessageID:    ID:414d5120414344534430513720202020537502dd201b6c02
  JMSTimestamp:    1405462485258
  JMSCorrelationID:bf566441-8ccb-4620-afac-941cc4842a61
  JMSDestination:  queue://QMGR01/REQUESTQ
  JMSReplyTo:      queue://QMGR01/RESPONSEQ
  JMSRedelivered:  false
  JMSXDeliveryCount:0
  JMSXAppID:Websphere MQ Client for Java
  JMS_IBM_PutApplType:28
  timestamp:1405462384810
  sequenceNumber:3
  JMSXUserID:mqcls1      
  sequenceSize:4
  JMS_IBM_PutTime:22574883
  JMS_IBM_PutDate:20140715
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Employee><empId>567</empId></<Employee>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that you get `MessageTimeoutException` and there is only one place in the `JmsOutboundGateway` where it is:

```
if (jmsReply == null) {
    if (this.requiresReply) {
        throw new MessageTimeoutException(message,
                "failed to receive JMS response within timeout of: " + this.receiveTimeout + "ms");
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hence your issue is around the `reply` not request. 
I mean you send the message to the destination properly, but the other side doesn't send a reply to you to the `responseQueue` destination.

If you aren't interest in `request/reply` scenario and it's just enough to send messages, you can switch to the `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

If it isn't truth, show, please, the StackTrace to see where your `MessageTimeoutException` is caused.

**UPDATE**

> Can this be because of JmsCorrelationId ?

Yes it can. The another part has to support the `JMSCorrelationID` property with a value from the `request`.

`JmsOutboundGateway` does the correlation by `selector`:

```
messageSelector = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + correlationId + "'";
...
messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(replyTo, messageSelector);
```

Comment: Thanks Artem for the reply. I deleted my previous comment because sending messages on request queue is not getting logged but i checked in actual messages were getting sent. Also i wrote another independent listener container listening on same queue where my outbound gateway is supposed to receive replies and it receives reply as soon as i send. Also i have to use gateway so any idea what could be wrong with my <int-jms:outbound-gateway> ?

Comment: Please check stacktrace in main post.

Comment: If have `independent listener` it steals messages for you gateway! Because `responseQueue` is a `Queue`, hence only one listener can get the message from queue. How about to remove it? :-)

Comment: I know that, independent listener was created only for testing just to check if receiver of my messages is sending reply back. And when my jms outbound gateway is running , i kept independent listener down.

Comment: Any expert advice please ?

Comment: Can this be because of JmsCorrelationId ?

Comment: Thanks Artem but i did not understand your update completely, so i do not need to do anything for correlationId , correct ? Also i have added the jms message i am sending , do you see anything incorrect in there ?

Comment: If you don't control the consumer part, you can do nothing with the `correlation`. Right. the consumer has to send a reply to the `reply-destination` with the `correlationId` from request. Otherwise the producer won't work.

Comment: Yes i donot have any control over consumer for the message i send (using outbound gateway). Thanks a lot Artem for your help.